URI for adding GeoPackage to ArcGIS Pro
I am trying to add a GeoPackage layer to current ArcGIS Pro 3.3 map using C# code. What should the syntax be for the URI?
I have tried straight path:
 LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer("D:\myFolder\myGeoPackage.gpkg\myLayer", MapView.Active.Map);

and I have tried this:
 LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer("geopackage:///D:\myFolder\myGeoPackage.gpkg?layer=myLayer", MapView.Active.Map);

Both throw a "Failed to create layer" error.

I recommend you explore the snippets on github. Here is one about adding a raster layer.  You can study the syntax.

Thanks. I have file based vectors and rasters working. It's just GeoPackages that I'm struggling with. Esri being Esri rarely promote how to work with open source formats...

TLDR:
LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer(new Uri(@"D:\MyGeoPackage.gpkg\main.MyLayerName", MapView.Active.Map);

I deduced this by running an ArcPro GeoProcessing tool and then looking at the logs to see how ArcPro itself formats the layer path...
